# how to get last 2 weeks from date using SQL

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I want to get the last 2 weeks based on current date.

suppose Today is Thursday but i want the data of last 2 weeks which is Monday to Sunday.

can i get the exact last 2 weeks which is starting from Monday and ending with Sunday.

How to obtain in sql ?

```
head(data)
"2018-07-01" 
"2018-07-01" 
"2018-07-01" 
"2018-07-01" 
"2018-07-01" 
"2018-07-01" ## date format in my data
```

Comment: What's your attempt so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the date_trunc function to truncate it to the beginning of the week and then subtract an interval of 1 week:

```
select  date_trunc('week', '2018-07-01'::timestamp) - interval '1 week';
```

Comment: u mentioned as week and can i get the data from Monday to Sunday of last week or from yesterday to last 6 days?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below

```
select * from yourtable where date>=date_trunc('week', current_date::timestamp) - interval '2 week'
and date<date_trunc('week', current_date::timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
SELECT current_date + cast(abs(extract(dow from current_date) - 7) + 1 as int) - interval '2 week' "lastMonday",
       current_date + cast(abs(extract(dow from current_date) - 7)  as int)    - interval '1 week' "lastSunday"
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=dbe806147d2e5d628c87f8f2deb3ac58)

**NOTE**

`current_date` can change your datetime.